# Index match function

Tags: excel

I have two columns in my spreadsheet, Column A and B both of same size. I have to call out a value from column B which will correspond(same index) to the highest value from column A. 
I am using Index-Match which works perfectly for only one highest value from column A. But I want to add another level of sorting for the case of two same highest values in column A.
Suppose, I have two maximums in column A which should give me two corresponding values from table B, from which I want to call out the lowest one.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example? What is currently happenning, what is your desired table output?

Answer (score -1):

If your data are in rows 1-10 of columns A & B with headers, you can use the following:-

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A10=MAX(A2:A10),B2:B10))
```

So the inner IF statement produces an array with the values of column B corresponding to the values in column A which are equal to the maximum value in column A, otherwise FALSE. MIN returns the lowest of these, ignoring the FALSE values.

This is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If it's possible to have blanks in column B, then you could ignore them with the following:-

```
=MIN(IF((A2:A10=MAX(A2:A10))*(B2:B10<>""),B2:B10))
```

otherwise the first formula will read them as zeroes.

[image]

Comment: My rep is a nice round number after that, thank you whoever you are. Perhaps time to take a little holiday from SO.

Comment: Thank you Tom. This helped.